# C# custom string split library, 

Tags: c#-4.0

Are their any custom c# string split scripts, that will enable a string to be split but still retain the split characters in each of the split strings.

For example, if I split "ABCD CRLF ABC" with first string retaining the carriage return/line feed resulting in two strings:

ABCD CRLF

ABC

Bob.

Comment: I'm reading lines from a file into byte buffer and need to ensure I don't lose the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is

```
string[] lines =  Regex.Split(inputString, @"(?<=\r\n)(?!$)");
```

Comment: Dmitri, that's exactly what i'm looking for. Wish I could give you some poing like experts exchange, but excellent quick answer.